# Troubleshooting failed updates on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, updates, windows-update

It's been a while since I've seen a Vista machine in the field, and I am now reminded of all the reasons why everybody hated this OS. I have about 30 failed updates with error codes ranging from cryptic to indecipherable/apparently meaningless. Googling these codes brings me to strange websites in China.

How to troubleshoot many failed updates?

Comment: upload the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS ad the file C:\Windows\Windowsupdate.log

Comment: Have you found the requested log files?

Comment: Haven't been back onsite yet. The computer belongs to a client of mine. I was looking for some general tips on how to go about getting these to install. I will upload when I can.

Comment: you can answer this generally. Without logs everything is pure speculation.